# How do I use the version number of a C++ program in the program itself?

Tags: c++, xcode, versioning

Xcode's build options include a `Current Project Version` variable, and I was wondering if there was any way to use that in a C++ program.

```
std::string version_info = "FooProgram " + /* magic here? */ ;
```

Comment: And that's how you learned using "autoconf"... =)

Comment: @H2CO3 What, you can use `autoconf` with Xcode?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Xcode.

Comment: @slugonamission I agree, seeing as how that's for Objective-C and iPhone development, and my question deals with C++ and has nothing to do with iPhones. ;)

Comment: @BlacklightShining - yes, but you can use the concept of the variables they explain to add a build variable (using `-Dfoo=bar`) to your compiler's command line.

Comment: @slugonamission …and now the question becomes how to make the version string available to _that._ XD

Comment: I'm not firing up XCode to test this, but use a similar concept to add the variable to GCC's command line.

Comment: @slugonamission Ahh, okay. Adding a preprocessor macro for `__PROJECT_VERSION__=\"${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}\"` solved this.